# Scaling mosquitto mqtt to more than 2 servers

Tags: mosquitto

All examples around scaling mosquitto mqtt servers provide bridge example which is suitable to scale maximum upto 2 node cluster. Can we have more than 2, say 10 mosquitto mqtt servers all connected to each other to scale total number of connections served?

Answer (score 1):

Don't see why not but consider 'should you' along with 'can you'!
What is it that you are trying to achieve - load balancing or high availability?

I don't see why bridging n=10 brokers is not possible - but probably not necessary or advisable.

MQTT is pretty efficient and can handle a huge number of connections so unless you are looking at millions of clients with lots of data, load balancing may not be needed at all.

For HA, with 2 brokers( servers) in 2 different datacenters, the chance of both going down is slim to none so as long as one can handle all the traffic you should be ok.

My clients connect from a DNS SRV record list of several broker addresses and connect to the next broker on the list when an existing connection fails. I suppose you could further decide which SRV list item to use first based on the client serial to spread them out across available brokers.

Bill

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks for the reply. The requirement is for supporting at least 5 million concurrent connections. Looking for a solution where I can have multiple mosquitto servers behind a load balancer for clients. I suppose bridge allows mosquitto to connect to at most to one server even when multiple are listed in the configuration. So technically I am unable to decide what would be the right way to connect more than 3 servers without creating loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with scaling try considering 
emqttd open source and free.

emqttd leverages power of Erlang VM with sufficiently powerful machine can 
scale upto 1 million connection on a node.

where mosquitto scales upto 10000 and upto 5000 only on ssl.

[emqttd clustering tutorial](http://emqtt.io/docs/v2/cluster.html#cluster-setup)